# How to replace just first space in file name by a string on multiple files in a directory?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

Does anyone know how to replace first space in a file name by a text like `_TEMP-` after the first 8 characters of the file name?

Also I was hoping to write a batch file that can change multiple files in a directory with similar file name structure.

For example:

**Before:** `12345678 Hello World.txt`

**After:** `12345678_TEMP-Hello World.txt`

Comment: sustring substitution with `set /?` or even better splitting the string with  `for /?` and reassembling.

Comment: You really should be more specific about the task. The question states that you wish to 'insert' `_TEMP-` after the `8th` character, but the `Before` and `After` text shows something different! Are you wanting to replace the `9th` character with `_TEMP-`? or 'replace' it only if it's a `space` otherwise 'insert' before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple code demonstrating usage of **FOR** for this task:

```
@echo off
set "FileName=12345678 Hello World.txt"
for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%FileName%") do echo ren "%FileName%" "%%I_TEMP-%%J"
set "FileName="
echo/
pause
```

The file name is assigned here to an environment variable.

The command **FOR** with option `/F` splits the file name string specified in double quotes up into substrings using the default delimiters space and horizontal tab.

With `tokens=1*` is defined that **first** space/tab delimited string is assigned to specified loop variable `I`. The asterisk is responsible for not further splitting up on spaces/tabs after first string and instead assign everything after space(s)/tab(s) after first string to next loop variable which is according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) the loop variable `J`. So for this example `I` gets assigned `12345678` and `J` gets assigned `Hello World.txt`

The command to execute is here **ECHO** which prints the command line for renaming the file which would be executed without `echo`.

Another batch code which renames all non hidden files in current directory with a space in file name not containing already `_TEMP-` in file name:

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%# in ('dir "* *" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /V /C:_TEMP- 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%%#") do ren "%%#" "%%I_TEMP-%%J"
)
```

The outer **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line:

```
dir "* *" /A-D-H /B 2>nul | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /L /V /C:_TEMP- 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches in current directory because of `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden) just for non hidden files matching the wildcard pattern `* *` and outputs just the found file names because of `/B` (bare format). An error message in case of no file matching these criteria is suppressed by redirecting the error message written to handle **STDERR** to the device **NUL**.

The file names output by **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** are redirected to **STDIN** of command **FINDSTR** which searches in the list of file names case-sensitive and literally for the string `_TEMP-`. But output are not the lines containing this string, but the inverted result because of `/V`. So output are by **FINDSTR** to handle **STDOUT** all lines **not** containing the string `_TEMP-`. A possible error message output by **FINDSTR** to handle **STDERR** is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

The outer **FOR** captures the output to **STDOUT** of background command process and then processes the captured output line by line. It is very important here to process a captured list of file names because the found files to modify in current directory are renamed by the command inside the **FOR** loop. Otherwise on using **FOR** itself to find files matching wildcard pattern `* *` it could happen that a renamed file is processed multiple times or some files are skipped because of list of files in current directory changes during loop execution.

Empty lines are always ignored by **FOR**, but the list of file names does not contain empty lines.

`for /F` would also ignore lines starting with a semicolon by default. This behavior is changed by specifying `eol=|` to skip lines starting with a vertical bar. File names can begin with a semicolon, but file names cannot contain a vertical bar. So it is made sure not skipping any file name with `eol=|`.

`for /F` with default options would split a line (file name) up on spaces/tabs and would assign just first substring to specified loop variable `#`. This behavior is not good here because the complete file name from filtered output of **DIR** is needed for the file renaming task. For that reason `delims=` is used specifying an empty list of delimiters resulting in no splitting up the line (file name) into substrings (tokens).

It could be that a file is named for example `12345678   Hello World.txt` with multiple spaces in series in file name. This is the reason for first getting assigned to loop variable `#` the complete file name as found by **DIR** in current directory.

The file name is split up into two substrings as explained above and then renamed which is successful if there is not already a file or folder with new name in current directory and the file to rename is not opened currently by an application with sharing access denied.

The batch file above could be coded also with a single command line in batch file:

```
@for /F "eol=| tokens=1*" %%I in ('dir "* *" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /V /C:_TEMP- 2^>nul') do @ren "%%I %%J" "%%I_TEMP-%%J"
```

Or the single command line is really executed directly in a command prompt window as follows with just one percent sign on referencing the loop variables `I` and `J`:

```
for /F "eol=| tokens=1*" %I in ('dir "* *" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /V /C:_TEMP- 2^>nul') do @ren "%I %J" "%I_TEMP-%J"
```

But this single command line version works only for files with always a single space character between first part and remaining part of file name, i.e. it works for `12345678 Hello World.txt` but does not work for `12345678   Hello World.txt`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Comment: Thank you @Mofi for your answer. This really works and exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the delay response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible batch file solution for replacing the 9th character with your given string, `_TEMP-`; *it utilises PowerShell*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SD=%UserProfile%\Documents"
PowerShell -C "GI '%SD%\???????? *.txt'|Ren -N {$_.BaseName.Remove(8,1).Insert(8,'_TEMP-')+$_.Extension} -Wh"
Pause
```

Just change `%UserProfile%\Documents` on line `2` to the folder containing the `.txt` files, *(if they're not really `.txt` files either, change `txt` on line `3` to the appropriate string or wildcard. If the string you wish to add is also different, please replace `_TEMP-` on line `3` with your desired string too)*. The script is currently designed to show you what would happen, were the files to be renamed; if you're happy with the output, change the script thus:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SD=%UserProfile%\Documents"
PowerShell -C "GI '%SD%\???????? *.txt'|Ren -N {$_.BaseName.Remove(8,1).Insert(8,'_TEMP-')+$_.Extension}"
```

---

If you didn't want to remove the <kbd>space</kbd> after those `8` characters, then:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SD=%UserProfile%\Documents"
PowerShell -C "GI '%SD%\???????? *.txt'|Ren -N {$_.BaseName.Insert(8,'_TEMP-')+$_.Extension} -Wh"
Pause
```

…and similarly if you're happy with the output, change the script to this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SD=%UserProfile%\Documents"
PowerShell -C "GI '%SD%\???????? *.txt'|Ren -N {$_.BaseName.Insert(8,'_TEMP-')+$_.Extension}"
```

---

*I'm sure there will be better ways of doing this, even with PowerShell, but given that your provided information is lacking, I'm unable to suggest anything else at this time.*